# How to persist the bottom Navigation bar while pushing multiple routes on one page while using auto_route in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, auto-route

I want to persist the bottom navigation bar throughout some parts of my app. I'm using `AutoTabsScaffold` while using the auto_route package. My home page has 3 tabs. Currently when i push any new route, it just replaces the home route entirely.

I'm using `AutoRouter.of(context).push` to push a new route onto the home page. I want it to not loose the navigation bar while pushing onto a new route so that i can navigate between the tabs easily.